# ServiceStack GetSession during heartbeat

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

I have a servicestack app in which I would like to make some session-related updates during heartbeat.
My simplified host code:

```
internal class SelfHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    public SelfHost() : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(ServerEventsService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature
        {
            LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = true,
            NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = false,
            OnHeartbeatInit = req =>
            {
                var userSession = req.GetSession();
                var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(req.GetSessionId());
            }
        });

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new CredentialsAuthProvider
                {
                    SessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    SkipPasswordVerificationForInProcessRequests = true,
                },
            })
            );

        var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);

        string hash;
        string salt;
        var pwd = "ValidPassword";

        new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString(pwd, out hash, out salt);
        userRep.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
        {
            Id = 3,
            DisplayName = "CustomDisplayName2",
            Email = "test2@gmail.com",
            UserName = "CustomUserName2",
            FirstName = "FirstName2",
            LastName = "LastName2",
            PasswordHash = hash,
            Salt = salt,
        }, pwd);
    }
}
```

and the simplified client code:

```
var mainClient = new ServerEventsClient(baseUrl, "home");

var authResponse = mainClient.Authenticate(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = "CustomUserName2",
    Password = "ValidPassword",
    RememberMe = false,
});

mainClient.Connect().Wait();
```

It connects and authenticates fine, the problematic part start in `OnHeartbeatInit` - my session here is always a new non authenticated session that has only Id, CreatedAt and LastModified. My service is marked with `[Authenticate]` attribute on class level. Have I misconfigured or lost some config that should allow that? If I post to my service and call `Request.GetSession()` then I get a populated session which I expect to see in `OnHeartbeatInit` as well.
Sidenote: there are no hidden configs anywhere, I have created a separate app exclusively for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the heartbeats requests sent in .NET `ServerEventsClient` isn't sent with the same `CookieContainer` that the client authenticates or connects to the `/event-stream` with, which is what contains the Session Cookies.

I've updated the `ServerEventsClient` so heartbeat requests now reference the same CookieContainer for every heartbeat request [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/6eca16bc6a44dbaf64feca7b25a2c19439ec74ec).

This change is available from v4.0.55 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Dropping cache (important) and reloading 4.0.55 version solved the issue, now i have no workarounds and only clean code.